How can other domains point to my server?
I recently bought a VPS to deploy my E-commerce.
I installed and configured Nginx, changed the default SSH PORT, and enabled the firewall so no port is accessible from outside. I created a user and granted the necessary privileges. After I configured the Domain name zones and Add the Type A rule to point to VPS, all good until now, no problems.
I came back to the server and added the necessary configs for my domain name, and its live .
After a few days I wanted to test if my domain name will appear in the top chrome search for some keywords. I received a different domain name as the top result and my domain at the bottom. After clicking the top domain (not mine), it rendered my website and I thought that there is someone that can login to my server and steal data, or some backdoor there.
I tested with another domain I have to point to my VPS, and it shows my website, am I doing something wrong or what is happening here?
I test it also with fb load balancer IP address and it worked even though I received the error:


If you can share something like a video clip, maybe people will be able to know what you meant more easily.

Ok have a look at these two domains mercerie  | winnow
Mine is mercerie, how the Hell is the other one pointing to my VPS IP with an A record ?? i checked the nginx configs and nothing suspicious  there, I deleted the default file, I checked many things

Domain owners can point their domain A and AAAA records to any IP address they choose. They can also specify multiple IP addresses. It is common for multiple domains to have the same IP address.
It is possible the domain was assigned your IP address in the past and its DNS record has not been updated to point to a new address.
The solution is to configure your web server to serve sites based on the requested domain. One of the sites getting served is defined as the default site. The default site serves content for unconfigured domains. Apache2 serves content from the first specified site if no other site matches the requested domain (or if no domain is specified).
The default site can be configured in many ways:

return a 404 for all requests;
redirect to a different site;
provide a minimal page;
or any other response the administrator desires.

It is common for the site configuration to support the domain with and without the "www." prefix. Alternatively, redirects are used to deliver content from only one of these variations.

Thank you, I've deleted the default file and I thought that would solve the issue, but its not, so I create it back and return 404 response to every 443 requests and its working.
Thank you
